# Java ExecutorService Task Spawning

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring, executorservice

I have an `ExecutorService` that is used to handle a stream of tasks. The tasks are represented by my `DaemonTask` class, and each task builds a response object which is passed to a response call (outside the scope of this question). I am using a `switch` statement to spawn the appropriate task based on a task id `int`. It looks something like;

```
//in my api listening thread
executorService.submit(DaemonTask.buildTask(int taskID));
```

---

```
//daemon task class
public abstract class DaemonTask implements Runnable {

    public static DaemonTask buildTask(int taskID) {
        switch(taskID) {
            case TASK_A_ID: return new WiggleTask();
            case TASK_B_ID: return new WobbleTask();
            // ...very long list ...
            case TASK_ZZZ_ID: return new WaggleTask();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        respond(execute());
    }

    public abstract Response execute();
}
```

---

All of my task classes (such as `WiggleTask()` ) `extend DaemonTask` and provide an implementation for the `execute()` method.

**My question is simply; is this pattern reasonable? Something feels wrong when I look at my huge switch case with all its return statements. I have tried to come up with a more elegant lookup table solution using reflection in some way but can't seem to figure out an approach that would work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need so many classes? You could have one method per taskId.

```
final ResponseHandler handler = ... // has many methods.

// use a map or array or enum to translate transIds into method names.
final Method method = handler.getClass().getMethod(taskArray[taskID]); 
executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
         method.invoke(handler);
    }
});
```

If you have to have many classes, you can do

```
// use a map or array or enum to translate transIds into methods.
final Runnable runs = Class.forName(taskClassArray[taskID]).newInstance(); 
executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
         runs.run();
    }
});
```

Comment: *This* was the reflection-based approach that I was trying to grasp. Thanks for clarifying it with two examples. The reason for separate classes is simply that the `execute()` methods in many cases are huge, some require libraries that others don't and so on. A class for each meant reasonably sized source files and avoided millions of imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `enum`:

```
public enum TaskBuilder
{
    // Task definitions
    TASK_A_ID(1){
        @Override
        public DaemonTask newTask()
        {
            return new WiggleTask();
        }
    },
    // etc

    // Build lookup map
    private static final Map<Integer, TaskBuilder> LOOKUP_MAP
        = new HashMap<Integer, TaskBuilder>();

    static {
        for (final TaskBuilder builder: values())
            LOOKUP_MAP.put(builder.taskID, builder);
    }

    private final int taskID;
    public abstract DaemonTask newTask();

    TaskBuilder(final int taskID)
    {
        this.taskID = taskID;
    }

    // Note: null needs to be handled somewhat
    public static TaskBuilder fromTaskID(final int taskID)
    {
        return LOOKUP_MAP.get(taskID);
    }
}
```

With such an enum, you can then do:

```
TaskBuilder.fromTaskID(taskID).newTask();
```

Another possibility is to use a constructor field instead of a method, that is, you use reflection. It is much easier to write and it works OK, but exception handling then becomes nothing short of a nightmare:

```
private enum TaskBuilder 
{                                                 
    TASK_ID_A(1, WiggleTask.class),
    // others

    // Build lookup map
    private static final Map<Integer, TaskBuilder> LOOKUP_MAP
        = new HashMap<Integer, TaskBuilder>();

    static {
        for (final TaskBuilder builder: values())
            LOOKUP_MAP.put(builder.taskID, builder);
    }

    private final int index;
    private final Constructor<? extends DaemonTask> constructor;

    TaskBuilder(final int index, final Class<? extends DaemonTask> c)
    {
        this.index = index;
        // This can fail...
        try {
            constructor = c.getConstructor();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    // Ewww, three exceptions :(    
    public DaemonTask newTask()
        throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
        InstantiationException
    {
        return constructor.newInstance();
    }

    // Note: null needs to be handled somewhat
    public static TaskBuilder fromTaskID(final int taskID)
    {
        return LOOKUP_MAP.get(taskID);
    }
}
```

This enum can be used the same way as the other one.

Comment: Nice use of overloading, I will remember this pattern, thanks!

Comment: There is more simple, though: you can add a class as an instance variable of an enum, and the `.newTask()` would then just be a `theClass.newInstance()`. Your choice ;) The advantage with abstract methods is that you can do a little more at initialization time.

Comment: I might end up using this, I'll move the accept over if I do. Thanks again for the ideas.